Why does this MOSFET load-switch cause current spike?
I made a custom PCB but I'm running into a problem: As soon as is set the GPIO to high there is a current spike (~1.4A) and causes the LDO to think its a short circuit and turn off, crashing the system.

If I bypass this circuit using a jumper wire everything works fine... Right before the circuit is a 3.3 V LDO, right after it are some ICs, capacitors and LEDs.
Now, I'm not entirely new to electrical engineering but I'm no expert either, yet I'm totally lost finding a reason why this current spike is happening. I have added 1 ohm resistors in series to the LDO-side side jumper, I checked the wiring etc.
If I use my desk powersuply and connect it to the jumper before the circuit, I can see the spike with my scope but the then the circuit runs fine....
I hope someone can explain this to me, I dont even know what to search for in Google. Thanks for your time!!

Drawing the circuit upside-down makes it difficult to read.

If the load includes substantial capacitance to ground then switching it on suddenly will cause a current spike. The P-channel MOSFET in that configuration can switch 'ON' very quickly in that configuration since the gate of the N-channel is being driven hard and it has a very low Rds(on).
Yu could try adding a 100kΩ resistor in series with the gate of the 2301 and reduce the pullup to 10kΩ. That will extend the turn on by virtue of the Miller effect and leave the turn-off time similar.
Here (with somewhat beefier SOT-23 MOSFETS) is a comparison of the two schemes:

The circuit without the gate resistors shows 18A spikes. With the resistor, the spike is only a couple mA (and you can see the steady-state 'on' current, which is so small in comparison to the spikes you can hardly see it in the first trace).

You probably have a capacitor across your load (a decoupling capacitor ?); it may be built-in to your load ?
When the PMOS switch closes, the capacitor gets charged, and this causes a surge.
You can a) add a (another) cap at the output of the LDO, or b) turn on the PMOS slowly -- put a 1 MΩ in series with its gate.

Thanks! I did try with the capacitor after the LDO but it didn't work... But now I understand the problem more clearly and the 1  MΩ series resistor sounds promising.
